# pycharm debug on m1 mac fails with: `pydevd_cython_darwin_310_64.cpython-310-darwin.so incompatible architecture`

Tags: python, pycharm, apple-m1

I just upgraded to pycharm 2022.01 and got an error when debugging a python program using m1 mac:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython_wrapper.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle_ext import pydevd_cython as mod
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pydevd_bundle_ext'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython_wrapper.py", line 11, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle import pydevd_cython as mod
ImportError: cannot import name 'pydevd_cython' from '_pydevd_bundle' (/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 55, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_trace_dispatch import (
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_trace_dispatch.py", line 42, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython_wrapper import trace_dispatch as _trace_dispatch, global_cache_skips, global_cache_frame_skips, fix_top_level_trace_and_get_trace_func
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython_wrapper.py", line 35, in <module>
    mod = getattr(__import__(check_name), mod_name)
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython_darwin_310_64.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython_darwin_310_64.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I installed the right version of pycharm. Couldn't find the right `.so` version on pypi.
How can I fix this? Is it possible to recompile pydevd for arm64e?

Comment: It doesn't look like you installed the native version.

Comment: I did reinstall it just to verify

Answer (score 4):

Managed to rebuild [`pydevd`](https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger) that comes with PyCharm:

#### Rebuild the binaries

Make sure you have [`cython`](https://pypi.org/project/Cython/) installed to update and compile the cython sources:

```
sudo pip3 install cython
export PYTHONPATH=/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev:$PYTHONPATH
cd /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev
python3.10 build_tools/build.py
```

After that, debugging in PyCharm worked fine.

#### Check the binaries

What the rebuild apparently did:

1. removed all `_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython_darwin_*.so` files
2. created only `_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython.cpython-310-darwin.so`

Use the [`file`](https://superuser.com/questions/180458/what-command-shows-the-architecture-of-a-binary-file-on-mac#180459) command to confirm the binary has the architecture required for new M1 (Apple Silicon) chips:

```sh
file _pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython.cpython-310-darwin.so`
```

It should output required architecture for M1 like `arm64` below:

```
_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython.cpython-310-darwin.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64
```

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem, and I can once again activate cython debugging.

Answer (score 1):

As a quickfix, you can simply disable cython debugging. This will still enable you to run a debugging session, albeit with less features.

Add this to the environment variables of your run configuration in PyCharm:

```
PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON=NO
```